# Get Apps Using WLAN & Cellular Setting

Tags: ios, iphone, setting

How to get `Apps Using WLAN & Cellular Setting` setting status in the picture below ?
How can I check that status(None, WLAN, WLAN&Cellular) for my App, so that I can show an alert to remind user of open this switch ~

[image]

Comment: You mean the setting for your app, not for all apps, correct?

Comment: Yep ,I want to guide user to open this switch.  Sometimes the wifi is connected, but this switch for my app is closed ,but users don't know this ,they may blame me cause they think something wrong with my app or server :(

Comment: There may be no way to do this - you may have to explain to the user what they need to do.

Answer (score 2):

When [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) is `NotReachable`, there are 2 situation ,

1. The wifi is not connected
2. The `Apps Using WLAN & Cellular Setting`
       is off

If we can get the SSID of current wifi, we can judge that the wifi is connected and the network switch is off ~

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>

    BOOL networkSwitchOff = NO;
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(status==NotReachable){  //Reachability NotReachable
        NSArray *supportedInterfaces = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
        id info = nil;
        NSString *ssid = nil;
        for (NSString *networkInfo in supportedInterfaces) {
            info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)networkInfo);
            if (info && [info count])
                break;
        }

        if (info) {
            NSDictionary *dctySSID = (NSDictionary *)info;
            //we can't get ssid if wifi is not connected
            ssid = [dctySSID objectForKey:@"SSID"]; 
        }
        networkSwitchOff = (ssid!=nil);
    }
```